# MSI runs as DOMAIN\SYSTEM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I've created an MSI, in Visual Studio. When running the MSI, it runs as `"DOMAIN\SYSTEM"`, I am trying to run this MSI using the current logged on user.

Is this possible?

Comment: ...but what are you really trying to accomplish? (The thing that makes you want to run it as the current user, or perhaps the thing that makes you want to do that.)

Comment: What I am doing is running the exe after install, but when the EXE runs it runs as SYSTEM, instead of the current user.

Answer (score 1):

An MSI is processed by msiexec.exe. This EXE runs in two contexts: client and server.

The client side is running as a PID in the context of who ever invoked it.   This covers Installation UI  (Anything listed in the InstalUISequence table).

The server side is running as a Windows Installer service in the SYSTEM context.  This covers things happening while the progress bar is displayed (Anything listed in the InstallExecuteSequence table).    Actions scheduled for immediate execution or deferred execution with impersonation will run in the context of the user who started msiexec.exe in the first place.  Deferred custom actions scheduled without impersonation  will run in the SYSTEM context of the host windows service running msiexec.exe.

If you are using a tool such as Systems Center Configuration Manager it is very likely (depending on how you configured the deployment)  that the SYSTEM account will have invoked the install so therefore everything will be running as SYSTEM.

The only way it's possible for the entire MSI to run in the user context would be to install in on Windows 95/98/ME. :)